# Is New Tuxedo approach really better than the earlier ones?

Tags: bioconductor

I am planning to perform multiple routine NGS analyses for a hospital lab on patients' samples on an everyday basis.

Before I used a new tuxedo approach with `ballgown` etc and was rather satisfied with it.

I wonder if for the above-mentioned job it's ok to use a ballgown or, perhaps, that is not the best choice?

Comment: I'm fairly used to analyse NGS illumina data, but what is the New Tuxedo approach you mention? How do you measure best choice?

Comment: Which kind of data are you working with? Doesn't a clinical setting require some kind of legal approval and validation of the pipelines you use? Please specify which data you have and what even the analysis goal is.

Comment: Thanks I am talking about this approach https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2016.095